# How can I fix this react-native dyld_process_snapshot_get_shared_cache failed

Tags: ios, typescript, react-native

I have crash issues with react native ios application.
This application build success.
But when started this app crashed.
Here is my error report.

The steps that I take to reproducibly cause this error are the following:

- typescript
- yarn add "react-native-test-app": "^1.3.1",
- yarn add "react-native-webview": "^11.18.0",
- Podfile -> platform :ios, '13.0'
- react-native run-ios

> Error Formulating Crash Report:
> dyld_process_snapshot_get_shared_cache failed
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL) Exception Codes:
> 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note:
> EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY Termination Reason: FRONTBOARD 2343432205
> <RBSTerminateContext| domain:10 code:0x8BADF00D
> explanation:[application<com.svcorps.project>:81632] failed to
> terminate gracefully after 5.0s ProcessVisibility: Unknown
> ProcessState: Running WatchdogEvent: process-exit WatchdogVisibility:
> Background WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds):
> 10.200 (user 5.210, system 4.990), 24% CPU", "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.045, 0% CPU" ) reportType:CrashLog
> maxTerminationResistance:Interactive>

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution? If so, could you please post it as I am too experiencing this issue when trying to open a release build on iOS simulator as well as physical device...

Comment: @dev1ce I have to reinstall react-native settings and Xcode

Comment: What exactly was your fix for this?